# How to select the count of joins as metadata for the main model using activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two tables that are something like:

```
users
  id
  name
  active

items
  id
  user_id
  color
```

Using Rails, I want to select the active users along with the number of items that are red or blue.

Something like:

```
User.where(active: true).joins(:items).where(items: {color: ['red', 'blue']}).count(:items)
```

I want the result to be an array of Users where the Users have an annotated number of items.

So it could end up like users = *activerecord query*, users.first.name == 'John', users.first.items_count == 3

What would you do?

Comment: Do you want users that have 0 red or blue items to be included?

Answer (score 0):

I don't say it is the solution, but this following statement

`Item
  .joins(:user)
  .group(:user_id)
  .where(users: { active: true }, color: ['red', 'blue'])
  .count`

return a list of `user_id` with its associated `item` count:

`{
 user_id_1 => count_1,
 user_id_2 => count_2,
 user_id_3 => count_3,
 ...
}`

Answer (score 0):

Considering the color filter, I'd just do the count in ruby.

```
class User

  scope :active, -> { where(active: true) }

  def items_of_color(colors)
    items.select{ |i| i.color.in?(colors) }
  end

end
```

in the controller

```
@users = User.active.preload(items)
```

and then in the view, count the red and blue

```
user.items_of_color(['red', 'blue']).size
```

But, if RED and BLUE are special and commonly referenced, you can do this...

```
class User
  ...
  has_many :red_and_blue_items, where -> ({color: ["red", "blue"]}), class_name: "Item"
end
```

And then, preload like so

```
@users = User.active.preload(:red_and_blue_items)
```

In the view

```
@users.first.red_and_blue_items.size
```